# R language: how to write for loop similar to java?

Tags: r

I'm used to writing `for` loops in Java using:

```
for (ii=10; ii<length(myarray); ii++) { }
```

If `length(my array)` is less than 10, the loop does NOT execute. How would I do this in R language?

If I try in R language:

```
for (ii in 10:length(myarray)) { }
```

The loop WILL execute if `length(myarray)` is less than 10, for example. How to write the loop so that it will NOT execute in this case?

Comment: `if (length(myarray) >= 10) { for (ii in 10:length(myarray)) { ... } }` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `if`.

```
if (length(myarray) >= 10) {
    for (ii in 10:length(myarray)) {...}
}
```

If this is too clear, you can use `while` to try to make R more Java-like

```
ii = 10
while (ii < length(myarray)) {
    ...
    ii = ii + 1
}
```

but I've never seen an R programmer do this. It does, as you say, replace the `if` and `for` with a single `while`, but it adds the need to initialize `ii` and increment it inside the loop.

Comment: Really? Is there nothing simpler within the `for` expression, perhaps using `seq` or other?

Comment: There is nothing *clearer*. This is the standard R way of doing things. For more Java-like code you could use a `while` loop instead. Or you could write an expression in your for loop that returns NULL if length(myarray) < 10, but it's just going to be using an `if` statement in a different place.

Comment: Thanks @gregor, I think a `while` loop would be cleaner if it replaces the `if` and `for` statements. If you add that, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @user46688: Write your Java loop however you want, but if you want to write the loop in R, you should really use `if`.

Comment: @gregor, thanks for outlining the options and making a recommendation.

Comment: Cleaner version: `for (ii in if (length(myarray)<10) NULL else 10:length(myarray)){...}` (just noticed @Gregor already mentioned this implicitly, I'll leave the explicit version here)

Answer (score 11):

You could use `for (ii in tail(seq_along(myarray), -9))`. `tail(..., -9)` will return `numeric(0)` when the length of `myarray` is less than 10.

Comment: Genius. Also, this kind of code is why comments were invented. Or wrap it in a function so you can do `for(ii in lastN(array, 10))` or `skipN` or whatever describes best what this does. And did I mention comments were a good idea?

Comment: It works, it's clever, enthusiastic +1, but I think the `if` is much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Well, this was what I asked for... but perhaps not as readable as an `if` or `while` statement. Thought there would be a simpler way, but guess not.

Comment: I prefer `for(i in seq_along(x[-1:-9]))`

Comment: Hi @experimenter, Where does `myarray` factor into this?

Comment: @experimenter off-by-9 error there: `for(i in 9+seq_along(x[-1:-9])){cat(i,"\n")}` (x is myarray)

Comment: Thanks, @Spacedman, comment added. PS., love [your geospatial cheatsheet](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/cheatsheet.html). It's helped me advocate for using R as a spatial solution.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, note that you can also do this by modifying the `seq` call:

```
for(i in seq(from=10, to=length(myarray), by=1) {...}
```

However, this will produce an error if `length(myarray)` is less than 10, as opposed to just not executing. Depending on what you're doing, this may or may not be desirable.